# "Thank Fred for something" or "Fred, thank you for something"

Tags: word-usage

Fred insisted on something, then I did the correct thing. I want to say a thank to him in a public comment (many people can read it).

> Thank Fred for your insistence.
>
> Fred, thank you for your insistence.

Which one is good?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to give a sensible answer to your question. Are you referring to social media, a letter to a newspaper or similar, or what? Although many people might be able to read it, would it make any sense to them?

Comment: "Insistence" or "assistance"?  I think "assistance" is more likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the correct form for your first structure is

> [**Thanks to**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thanks+to+somebody%2Fsomething) Fred for **his** insistence

Notice the 's' in Thanks, the particle "to" and the possesive "his".

Both of them are correct. Their use depends on your intentions.

**Thanks to Fred for**

This one is ment to be directed to an audience, a group of people.
You are trying to be grateful to Fred so that they recognize Fred's contribution to your work, you are somehow sharing with him the honour. I'd use this one in your case.

**Fred, thank you for**

This one is ment to adress Fred **directly**. You may or not be in front of an audience. In the second case, usually you are pointing to that person and the TV camera is centered in him.

EDITED with alternative offered by @Andrew

You can also use **Thanks, Fred, for your insistence** to address Fred in a public comment.

Comment: It's not wrong to address Fred directly in a public comment, **"Thanks, Fred, for your assistance."**  Your answer suggests this would be incorrect, and that OP should only address Fred in the third person.

Comment: @Andrew Is there any difference between "Fred, thank you" and "Thanks, Fred"? [Not being ironic]

Comment: In my opinion, "thanks" is more informal, but nevertheless common at least in the U.S.

Comment: @Andrew You have edited my text but OP was talking about "insistence" and not "assistance". I changed your comment to make it consisten with the rest.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I expect that's OP's mistake, though.  It would be weird to thank someone for their *insistence*.

Comment: @Andrew It's not so weird. Maybe Fred insisted in that it can be done/it can be fixed/the problem were in that module, whatever, and finally, thanks to him, the project ended well.  Who knows? ;-P